# How to set the cookie for a POST Request

Tags: swift3, alamofire

We are desperately trying to set a cookie before doing a POST request with Alamofire in Swift3. We only have found solutions for Swift2. Our current code looks like this

```
Alamofire.request(url, headers: NetworkUtil.getApiKeyHeader())
         .responseJSON { response in
             if let JSON = response.result.value {
                 print("JSON: \(JSON)")
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quit simple in the end, if you adapt it from Swift 2

```
if userCookie != nil, let cookieStorage = Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration.httpCookieStorage {
        cookieStorage.setCookies([userCookie!], for: url, mainDocumentURL: nil)
    }
```